# Struggling to prove Newton's Law of Gravitation starting from smaller bodies

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, vectors, tidal-effect

I have seen at least four different posts in this website in which the OP asks for a proof of Newton's Law of Gravitation (often without stating from which axioms the proof should start) all of which have at least one answer or comment explaining the issue with expecting a mathematical proof for every formula in physics. I understand this.

---

That being said, Newton's Law of Gravitation can be applied to any pair of bodies, for example myself and the laptop in fron of me. My idea is the following: there is a force between every particle in my body and every particle in Earth, and the sum of all these forces can be (approximately) expressed as

$$G\frac{mM}{d^2}$$

where $M$ is Earth's mass and the distance $d$ is taken between my and the Earth's center of mass. More formally, if there is a body (a single particle, perhaps) with mass $m_b$ in space at distance $d$ from Earth's center of gravity, then the following should hold:

$$\sum_kG\frac{m_bm_k}{d_k^2}=G\frac{mM}{d^2}$$

where the sum is taken over a set of bodies which cummulatively constitute Earth, each of this bodies with mass $m_k$ and at distance $d_k$ from $b$. *This* is what I'm trying to prove.

---

My attempt: it should be sufficient to prove the formula works when summing over two bodies, since once this is done an argument by induction can be made for any arbitrary number of bodies.

More formally, let $b$ be a body with mass $m_b$ and let $B$ be a body with mass $M$ so that $\vec{r_0}$ is a vector from $b$'s center of mass to $B$'s center of mass. Furthermore suppose that $B$ can be divided into the bodies $B_1$ and $B_2$ with masses $M_1$ and $M_2$ respectively, and let $\vec{r_1}$ and $\vec{r_2}$ be vectors from their respective center of mass to $B$'s center of mass. We must show that

$$G\frac{m_bM_1}{\Big|\vec{r_0}+\vec{r_1}\Big|^2} + G\frac{m_bM_2}{\Big|\vec{r_0}+\vec{r_2}\Big|^2}=G\frac{m_bM}{\Big|\vec{r_0}\Big|^2}$$

Noting that $M_1|\vec{r_1}|=M_2|\vec{r_2}|$ and that $M=M_1+M_2=M_1+\frac{|\vec{r_1}|}{|\vec{r_2}|}M_1$, the equation above can be seen to hold if and only if

$$\frac{1}{\Big|\vec{r_0}+\vec{r_1}\Big|^2} + \frac{|\vec{r_1}|/|\vec{r_2}|}{\Big|\vec{r_0}+\vec{r_2}\Big|^2}=\frac{1+|\vec{r_1}|/|\vec{r_2}|}{\Big|\vec{r_0}\Big|^2}$$

yet this reation does not hold in general. Simply take $b$ to be situated at the origin (exploit notation to say $b=(0,0)$) and $B=(0,-4)$, $B_1=(-4,-4)$, $B_2=(-4,3)$. What am I missing?

---

PS: if there is something that isn't clearly explained or some other reason for downvoting, I'd appreciate a comment explaining the reason to downvote so that I can modify the question accordingly.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I'm merely adding the magnitudes of the forces and not the forces themselves, I'll be busy for a while and will have to check later how to really approach this.

Comment: Have you heard about the shell theorem?

Comment: In addition, why do you believe the shell theorem can be proven using induction at all? It’s a statement about the gravitation force from a sphere, not a collection of point masses.

Comment: To add to this, the shell theorem (or Gauss' Law for gravity) is an *axiomatic* approach to deriving the gravitational law. The gravitational field lines radiating outward is the only a priori knowledge needed to demonstrate the inverse square law.

Comment: Do you know how to integrate? That’s how you “add up” all the forces for continuous mass distributions.

Comment: @MichaelBurt Most physicists would consider that backwards. You start with the inverse square law for two point masses (the simplest situation) and from it you derive the gravitational force between mass distributions.

Comment: @G.Smith Fair enough, but I would argue that whether you take the inverse square law or Gauss' law as the axiomatic starting point is arbitrary.

Comment: I was assuming that Newton's Law of Gravitation can be applied between any two masses, which apparently is false. I see now that the law applies to point particles, and that, as @knzhou mentioned, it can be proven as in Shell's theorem that if the body is spherical, then the force by which it attracts outside bodies can be computed as if the mass of the object was concentrated at it's center. This proof, although starting from different assumptions than mine, is more than enough. I had not heard of Shell's theorem nor of Gauss' Law of gravity, so I appreciate you mentioning them.